# Using the same block in a django template to display different information depending on a variable

Tags: django, templates, inheritance, django-templates, if-statement

Hey Mr. Stack overflow!
I am trying to have different information display in the same block depending on a variable "choice" which is simply an int.  The way I was planning on doing so was going to be something like the bellow code:

```
{% extends "index.html"%}

{%block head%}
    <p><h1>Welcome to Piss && ink {{user}}</h1></p>
{%endblock head%}   

{%block one%}     
    <p>The temperature in {{city}} is {{temperature}}&deg </p>
{%endblock one%}

{%if choice1 == 2 %}
    {%block two%}     
        <p>The temperature in {{city}} is {{temperature}}&deg </p>
    {%endblock two%}
{% endif %}

{%comment%}
    {%if choice1 == 2 %}
        {%block two%}
            <p>The temperature in {{city}} is {{temperature}}&deg </p>
        {%endblock%}
    {% endif %}
{%endcomment%}

{%block two%}
    <form method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {% if new_event %}
        <b><p>{{new_event}}</p></b>
    {% endif %}
{%endblock%}
```

Now, the problem I am having is that the template doesn't like that there are two blocks of the same name in the template.  For some reason it doesn't seem to care about the `{% if %}` statement that is checking where the `{% block %}` is supposed to go.  I thought that the `{% if %}` statement would only execute what was inside itself depending on its parameters but it doesn't seem to be doing that. It displays everything inside the `{% if %}` no matter what "choice1" is equal too :(  Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to fix this?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Put the logic inside the block instead of having two blocks of the same name.

**Instead of:**

```
{%if choice1 == 2 %}
    {%block two%}     
        <p>The temperature in {{city}} is {{temperature}}&deg </p>
    {%endblock two%}
{% endif %}

{%comment%}
    {%if choice1 == 2 %}
        {%block two%}
            <p>The temperature in {{city}} is {{temperature}}&deg </p>
        {%endblock%}
    {% endif %}
{%endcomment%}

{%block two%}
    <form method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {% if new_event %}
        <b><p>{{new_event}}</p></b>
    {% endif %}
{%endblock%}
```

**use:**

```
{% block two %}
    {% if choice1 == 2 %}
        <p>The temperature in {{city}} is {{temperature}}&deg </p>
    {% else %}
        <form method="post">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {% if new_event %}
            <b><p>{{new_event}}</p></b>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the if inside the block.  One block, two if statements

```
{% block two %}
    {% if choice == 1 %}
        <p>Some Content</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if choice == 2 %}
        <p>Other Content</p>
    {% endif %
{% endblock two %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this (if the templates differ a lot) would be to do something along the lines of:

```
{% extends choice_template %}
```

and set choice_template in the view.